# Funnel Report Type For Single Opportunity

Tags: reporting, custom-reports

I am new to reports so apologies for the newb question.

I want to put a Funnel Report on each Opportunity record. I have it set up successfully in the UI but I am not sure how to create the report with the data I want. It seems like I have to have a grouping no matter what and I am not sure what to group it by as it is a single Opportunity. I think I am missing something super simple so I was hoping someone could point it out. On the Opportunity object I have all the fields: Amount Raised, Total Amount, and Amount Needed (formula based off of Total Amount - Amount Raised). This is what I want it to look like, what it currently looks like, and what the report on the back end looks like.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A funnel on a single opportunity record is out of the box - it shows Amount by Stage.

Comment: @identigral I don't want to group by a single field type, I want to have the funnel reflect data from two custom currency fields I have created on Opportunity and I want the funnel to reflect that single Opportunity's data. Is this possible without having to custom code a chart?

Comment: If you build a report (and dashboard as visualization) that does what you want for (say) 100 opportunity records, then the same report (and dashboard) will work for 1 opportunity record. Give it another shot.